# Is that possible to use html <href> to create a pdf download link?

Tags: html, pdf

```
<a href="pdf/s7edge.pdf" class="special" target="blank">+<img src="s7 new.png" title=" 三星 S7" width="280" height="120" style="border:solid;">
```

Here is my code, after I click on my image link it shows me blank page.

[image: blank page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the html attribute "download" here is the final code:

```
<a href="pdf/s7edge.pdf" class="special" target="blank" download>+<img src="s7 new.png" title=" 三星 S7" width="280" height="120" style="border:solid;">
```